# PHP - is there a speed advantage for using ! instead of empty()?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

Is the ! operator faster than empty()?

Testing ! operator:

```
    $start_ts = microtime(true);
    $someVar = true;
    $_10M = 10000000;
    for($i = 0; $i < $_10M; $i++) {
        if(!$someVar) {

        }
    }
    $end_ts = microtime(true);
    die(var_dump($end_ts - $start_ts));
```

Testing empty():

```
    $start_ts = microtime(true);
    $someVar = true;
    $_10M = 10000000;
    for($i = 0; $i < $_10M; $i++) {
        if(empty($someVar)) {

        }
    }
    $end_ts = microtime(true);
    die(var_dump($end_ts - $start_ts));
```

They both take about 1.3 seconds to run.

Why isn't a function call slower than using ! operator? Isn't there overhead for calling empty()?

I thought the empty() call would be slower but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: _why isn't a function call slower than using ! operator?_ Actually, that's not quite a function, but native language construct

Answer (score 2):

1. It doesn't matter.
2. **It doesn't matter.**
3. `empty` is not a function, it's a *language construct*. It's more like an operator.
4. **Write what you mean.** The important difference between `!` and `empty` is that with `empty` it's expected and okay *if the variable doesn't exist at all*. That essentially turns off error reporting and makes it hard to find problems if you've typoed the variable name. Only ever use `empty` if it's legitimately expected that the value may not exist at all.
5. Something something various caches warmup speedup *cough cough*.
6. ***It doesn't matter.***

Meaning: In practice you should never ever care about the (hardly existing, see 3.) difference, since it's not any sort of important criterion for anything (see 4.). If you really want to know, dig into the C source code. But that is not knowledge that's in any way relevant to anyone writing PHP code.

Comment: My question asks nothing about difference between ! and empty() as I am well aware of that. So I can't accept this as an answer as the original question is not answered. I simply asked a theoretical question of which is faster, according to my tests they're pretty much the same. I don't see how your subjective opinion "it doesn't matter" is related to my question.

Comment: @Tool Well, point 3 somewhat addresses your question. It's not a function, so why do you expect a specific difference? And you've already figured out that there is none. And in practice you should never ever care about it, since it's not any sort of important criterion. If you really want to know, dig into the C code. But that is not knowledge that's in any way relevant to anyone writing PHP code.

Comment: Thanks - this makes more sense to me. If you rewrite your answer to be more like this comment, I'll accept it.